# shorten the string to the desired values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a "Link" attribute. It has the following meaning:

```
<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$14612">INC102</a>
<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$146122">INC1020</a>
<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$1461">INC10200</a>
```

I want to get the following result:

```
INC102
INC1020
INC10200
```

I need to leave the INC and the numbers after it without .
Tell me which command will help here? Since I understand that "Substr" will not work here.
I am use SQL Developer - Oracle

Comment: Which language are you using? From where you want to take the input? Please add the relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to extract "INC" with the following digits, use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(link, 'INC[0-9]+')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f2d6bd680b7a8c7e0ead729773db52b2) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I understand that "Substr" will not work here.

Says who?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$14612">INC102</a>'   from dual union all
  3     select '<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$146122">INC1020</a>' from dual union all
  4     select '<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$1461">INC10200</a>'  from dual
  5    )
  6  select
  7    substr(col,
  8           instr(col, '>') + 1,
  9           instr(col, '<', instr(col, '>')) - instr(col, '>') - 1
 10          ) result
 11  from test;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

INC102
INC1020
INC10200

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #1 - 5: sample data
- line #8: starting point of the `SUBSTR` function is one character after the first `>` sign
- line #9: length (used as the 3rd parameter of the `SUBSTR`) is position of the first `<` that follows the first `>` *minus* position of the first `>`

And that's it ... why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

You could treat `[<>]` as the word delimiter and take the second word:

```
with test (col) as
   ( select '<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$14612">INC102</a>'   from dual union all
     select '<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$146122">INC1020</a>' from dual union all
     select '<a href="https://help.company.ru/operator/#uuid:serviceCall$1461">INC10200</a>'  from dual
   )
select regexp_substr(col,'[^<>]+', 1, 2)
from   test;

REGEXP_SUBSTR(COL,'[^<>]+',1,2)
-------------------------------
INC102
INC1020
INC10200
```